# How can I read words in line?

Tags: python

This is what I did. The questions will be at the end.

1) I first opened a .txt document using `open().read()` to run a function as follows:

```
def clean_text_passage(a_text_string):
    new_passage=[]
    p=[line+'\n' for line in a_text_string.split('\n')]
    passage = [w.lower().replace('</b>\n', '\n') for w in p]

    if len(passage[0].strip())>0:
       if len(passage[1].strip())>0:
           new_passage.append(passage[0])
    return new_passage
```

2) Using the returned `new_passage`, I converted words into lines of words using the following command:

```
newone = "".join(new_passage)
```

3) Then, ran another function as follows:

```
def replace(filename):
    match = re.sub(r'[^\s^\w+]risk', 'risk', filename)
    match2 = re.sub(r'risk[^\s^\-]+', 'risk', match)
    match3 = re.sub(r'risk\w+', 'risk', match2)
    return match3
```

Up to this point, everything words fine. Now here is the problem. When I print `match3`:

```
i agree to the following terms regarding my employment or continued employment
with dell computer corporation or a subsidiary or affiliate of dell computer
corporation (collectively, "dell").
```

Looks the words are in lines. But,

4) I ran the last function by `convert = count_words(match3)` as follows:

```
def count_words(newstring):
     from collections import defaultdict
     word_dict=defaultdict(int)
     for line in newstring:
    words=line.lower().split()
    for word in words:
        word_dict[word]+=1
```

When I print `word_dict`, it shows as follows:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'"': 2, "'": 1, '&': 4, ')': 3, '(': 3, '-': 4, ',': 4, '.': 9, '1': 7, '0': 8, '3': 2, '2': 3, '5': 2, '4': 2, '7': 2, '9': 2, '8': 1, ';': 4, ':': 2, 'a': 67, 'c': 34, 'b': 18, 'e': 114, 'd': 44, 'g': 15, 'f': 23, 'i': 71, 'h': 22, 'k': 10, 'j': 2, 'm': 31, 'l': 43, 'o': 79, 'n': 69, 'p': 27, 's': 56, 'r': 72, 'u': 19, 't': 81, 'w': 4, 'v': 3, 'y': 16, 'x': 3})
```

Because the objective of my codes is to count a particular word, I need words like 'risk' in lines (i.e., I like to take risk) instead of 'I', 'l', 'i'

Question: how can I make `match3` contain words in the same fashion that we get by using `readlines()` so that I can count words in a line??

When I save `match3` as a .txt file, reopen it using `readlines()`, and then run the count function, it works fine. I do want to know how to make it work without saving and reopening it using `readlines()`?

Thanks. I hope I could figure this out so that I could sleep.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`for line in newstring` means iter one char by one

```
def count_words(newstring):
     from collections import defaultdict
     word_dict=defaultdict(int)
     for line in newstring.split('\n'):
         words=line.lower().split()
         for word in words:
            word_dict[word]+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr, the question is how do you split a text by lines?

Then it’s rather simple:

```
>>> text = '''This is a
longer text going
over multiple lines
until the string
ends.'''
>>> text.split('\n')
['This is a', 'longer text going', 'over multiple lines', 'until the string', 'ends.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `match3` is a string, so

```
for line in newstring:
```

iterates over the *characters* in newstring, not the lines.  You could simply write

```
 words = newstring.lower().split()
 for word in words:
     word_dict[word]+=1
```

or if you preferred

```
 for line in newstring.splitlines():
     words=line.lower().split()
     for word in words:
         word_dict[word]+=1
```

or whatever.  [I'd use a `Counter` myself, but `defaultdict(int)` is almost as good.]

NOTE:

```
def replace(filename):
```

`filename` is not a filename!